# What is the scene limits for alexa?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I´m writing a skill for Alexa and I want to submit some Scenes. If I send to Alexa, during the discovery process, more than 110 scenes she returns me only 110.
It seems that is the maximum allowed, am I right?
According to the Alexa guideline, there is no limit for this. (image below)

[image]

Does anyone had experienced the same?
What is your advice?

Tks in advance